# nasm sum of real number array, assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

this is an extension to my previous post, here is the updated code,
so far it will ouput the last number I inputed into the array, so it's not actually summing values yet

```
;*************************************ADD ARRAY**********************************************
segment .bss
sum     resq    1
segment .data
summessage  db  "The Sum is: ", 0
segment .text
extern readdouble,print_string, read_int, writedouble, print_nl, print_int
    global addarray
addarray:
    pusha
    mov edi, 0      ;initialize counter to 0
    mov esi, 0      ;initialize accum to 0
    ;mov    ecx, 0      ;zero out ecx and edx
    ;mov    edx, 0

    mov ebx, [ebp]  ;moves starting location of array1 into ebx
    mov edi, [ebp+12]   ;moves array size
add_loop:
    mov ecx, [ebx]  ;mov higher order
    mov edx, [ebx+4]    ;mov lower order

    push ecx
    push edx

    fldz
        fld     qword [esp]                    ;The second input is now in a floating point register, specifically st0.
        pop     dword ecx 
        pop     dword edx                      ;The first input is now on top of the system stack (the stack addressed by bytes)

    fadd    qword [esp]                    ;The first input is added to the second input and the sum
                                       ;replaces the second input in st0

    add ebx,8
    inc esi

    cmp edi, esi
    jz  add_done
    jmp add_loop
add_done:
    call    print_nl
    mov     eax, summessage                ;Setup to display a message
        call    print_string                   ;Dr. Carter's library

        push    dword 0                      ;Make space on sytem stack for the sum value
        push    dword 0                      ;Ditto
        fst     qword [esp]                    ;Copy contents of st0 to space currently on top of the system stack
        pop     edx                            ;Copy 4 MSBs to ecx
        pop     ecx                            ;Copy 4 LSBs to ecx

        call    writedouble                    ;Show the 8-byte value
        call    print_nl                       ;Newline

    popa
    ret
```

Comment: there is no question in this post.

Comment: you should post this in the original question if this is an extension.

Comment: the question is, if somebody could add some insight as to why it's not summing and printing out the correct sum value, as of right now its only printing out the last value I inputed into the array

Comment: sorry i thought i posted the addarray procedure, i edited the post, now it's the correct code

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that having `fldz` inside the loop is probably at least part of your problem.

Your loop to add the numbers looks a bit...strange to me. I think I'd use something more like this [warning: I mostly use MASM, so I used its syntax here...]:

```
add_array proc 
    mov  esi, [ebp]
    mov  ecx, [ebp+12] ; I'm assuming these are the right offsets
    fldz
add_loop:
    fadd  qword ptr [esi]
    add   esi, 8
    dec   ecx
    jnz   add_loop
    fstp  result
    ret
add_array endp
```